# Rails/Devise - Add ruby code in a locale file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locale, devise

I would like to know if there is a way to add ruby code in a locale file. For example:

```
  devise:
    failure:
      unconfirmed: 'You have to confirm your account before continuing. <%= link to "send confirmation instructions?", user_confirmation_path %>'
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I changed the yml file by adding .erb on the end of file name and that seems to work. I'm making this a comment instead of a solution here because I just did this and not sure yet if there will be any ramifications elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I have solved this in the past is:

```
devise:
  failure:
    unconfirmed: 'You have to confirm your account before continuing. {{confirm_link}}.'
    confirm_link_text: "send confirmation instructions?"
```

Then where you need the output:

```
t('devise.failure.unconfirmed',
  :confirm_link => link_to(
                           t('devise.failure.confirm_link_text'), 
                           user_confirmation_path)
                          )
```

Comment: it works great. I've just have to add .html_safe, but using devise as my authentication solution, I don't know where I have to put the output. Thanks for any idea!

Comment: Any idea where to add the .html_safe?